# How to update firmware of unbranded router?

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, firmware

I have an unbranded portable mini router and would like to update it's firmware. It is an old device, but I use it sparingly to connect one or two devices only, so I'm not very interested in replacing it for the time being.

I'm open to all possibilities:

1. Install a compatible OEM firmware
2. Install OpenWRT or DD-WRT

The problem is, since it is unbranded, I do not know which firmware would be compatible with my router.

The only information I have from the router's administration interface is the following:

- SDK Version: WA 352.4 (May 30 2011)
- System platform: RT5350 embedded switch

It is a mini router with an ethernet port and a reset button on one side and a mini-USB for power and an AP/WIFI microswitch on the other.

Is there a way I can discover what firmware is compatible with this device?

Comment: If you can't identify it, we can't verify if it supports third-party firmware, and obviously specific recommendations are out of scope.  Due to its age, it doesn't support any of the faster 802.11 standards, I simply suggest to replace it with something you can identify.

Comment: Correct upgrade path for no-name equipment - recycle it and get something that's not junque.